ExcelScript Conditional Formatting Error by column selection?
I am trying to filter and highlight.
I need to highlight specific values in specific columns that I want to be able to pick. SO:
an example
I want to be able to click "run" and have the script highlight the cells that have a value over 144.99 in them but also have the exact header as "VALUES". The script should search the entire document for this. It can't use the exact Column letter because that can change. It is usually under 100 rows down, fewer than 'DA' columns.
Here is what the automated thing gave me:
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // Auto fit the columns of all cells on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange().getFormat().autofitColumns();
    let conditionalFormatting: ExcelScript.ConditionalFormat;
    // Create custom from all cells on selectedSheet
    conditionalFormatting = selectedSheet.getRange().addConditionalFormat(ExcelScript.ConditionalFormatType.custom);
    conditionalFormatting.getCustom().getRule().setFormula(=IF(AND(A$1=VALUES,OR(A1>149.99)),TRUE,FALSE));
    conditionalFormatting.getCustom().getFormat().getFill().setColor("#ffcccc");
    conditionalFormatting.getCustom().getFormat().getFont().setColor("#c00000");
    conditionalFormatting.setStopIfTrue(false);
    conditionalFormatting.setPriority(0);
    let selectedCell = workbook.getActiveCell();
    // Select cell on selectedSheet offset by 0 row(s) on column 4 relative to selectedCell
    selectedCell.getEntireRow().getColumn(0).select();
}

